# Using a dynamic IP address for the service provider in a WSDL file

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

We're running a soap server using PHP, and currently the IP address is hard coded in the WSDL file for providing operations etc. However, there are plans to have the server on larger networks where it may not be able to dictate it's own IP address, and so it needs to allow a dynamic address.

Here's a couple of examples of places with this static IP address.

```
<wsdl:definitions name="itl_ukmachines" targetNamespace="http://10.10.8.89/InPrServerSys/sp/service.php" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://10.10.8.89/InPrServerSys/sp/service.php" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

and

```
<wsdl:operation name="MachineHostPowerUpRegistration">

    <soap:operation
    soapAction="http://10.10.8.89/InPrServerSys/sp/service.php/MachineHostPowerUpRegistration" />
    <wsdl:input>

        <soap:body use="literal" />
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>

        <soap:body use="literal" />
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Is there a way to have the php server replace these IP addresses up with it's current IP address on startup, or simply a special value that can go in there so this will work?

Comment: The issue is the networks we're on may or may not be connected to the Internet to allow them to upload usage statistics etc. At which point we're likely to get issues trying to run DNS on our device.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying at all. DNS can work in internal networks, on the internet, and both - doesn't have to return the same IP (or set of IPs) internally and externally.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't really clear there. My point is that we're potentially connecting onto networks we have no control over, so we can't prevent any potential conflicts with DNS. If they just wire up our devices on a new network, it's fine. If they connect us to their existing infrastrcuture, to allow an internet connection, there may already be a DNS server on there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the clients to be able to consume your service without any need of  configuration on their side, you will have to dynamically generate the WSDL whenever it is being requested.

Many platforms enable such behavior. For example take Axis: If you have a service at `http://Url/MyService` you'd also have the WSDL for the service accessible at `http://Url/MyService?wsdl`. The WSDL is generated each time.

I don't know what tools you have at your disposal, but you can easily achieve the same behavior even with plain PHP. First, replace the IPs with an easier placeholder string (e.g. `BaseURL`), then when wsdl is being requested just read the WSDL file from the filesystem, dynamically replace all `BaseURL` string with the current actual URL and return it.

Depending on what you are using as a library/framework there might be an out-of-the-box way to do the same thing with just a configuration, so investigate first.

Good luck!

Comment: Not ideal as we're running this on a fairly low powered ARM processor, but it looks like this is going to be the best way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help! WSDL will ideally be accessed, only once per consumer so it shouldn't be a big performance issue. If you want you can always implement some form of caching - e.g. generate the file on the first call and save it on the file system, then regenerate it again on a next call if its creation date is back more than X hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

Another clean solution is to override the location of our web service from client side, for example:

```
$soapClient->__setLocation('http://www.example.com/soapservice');
```